# Verify this limit is wrong with the definition

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Consider $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} n^2 2^n = 0$$

By the definition: $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists M_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that $\forall n > M_{\epsilon}$ we have $|f(n) - \ell| < \epsilon$

Applying the definition I write $$n^2 2^n < \epsilon$$

Now to show this is not true $\forall \epsilon$, I thought about this: $n^2 \leq 2^n$ for $n\geq 4$. Since $n\to +\infty$ this should hold true no matter what.
Then

$$n^2 2^n \leq n^4 \leq \epsilon$$

Now it suffices to take $\epsilon = 1/2$ to prove there is no such $n > M_{\epsilon}$, indeed

$$n^4 < \frac{1}{2}$$
But I get confused:

- For $n = 0$ the inequality actually holds.
- I cannot recover the form $n > M_{\epsilon}$ as asked in the definition

I still have many problems in understanding how those things work...

Thank you!

Comment: For $n>4$ this is not true $$2^n \leq n^2$$ for example put $n=10$ is it true  ? $$2^{10}=1024 \\ n^2=100 \\1024 <100 \  ?$$

Comment: You need to look carefully at the definition of limits. For better understanding, ask yourself questions such as - 'what does it mean when we say $l$ is not the limit of a given sequence $\{a_n\}$?' Also - is it necessary that all sequences should have a limit? Further, there is a mistake in your inequality - $n^2 \leq 2^n$ for $n\geq 4$ and not the other way round.

Comment: @Khosrotash Sorry, I reversed the inequality. I clearly wanted to state $n^2 \leq 2^n$ for $n\geq 4$. Going to edit.

Comment: To show that $~n^2 \leq 2^n,~$ for $~n \geq 4,~$ let $~a_n = n^2, b_n = 2^n.~$  Then, **inductively assuming** that $~a_n \leq b_n,~$ you have that $~a_{n+1} = a_n \times \left[\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right]^2,~$ while $~b_{n+1} = b_n \times 2.$

Comment: Prove $n^22^n \geq n$. Then you can just choose $n > \epsilon$ and you're done.